# using intel appframework ui design and its working fine in broweser but not working in html5 app . not showing colors only black everything

Tags: android, html, web-applications, appframework

I'm new to HTML5 webapp. I'm using the UI kit source code of the Intel framework UI. Everything works fine but I'm not getting any colour in my app.

When I run that files in browser it runs fine. But in both the emulator and the device, it's going black all background.

I have tried to remove some CSS parts, and getting somewhere some colors - but not all.

I have tried and removed `#afui .header` to header. It's showing some color, but not in all of it.

Answer (score 0):

To disable custom operating system themes, set $.afui.useOSThemes to false.

Read [this](https://app-framework-software.intel.com/documentation.php#afui/afui_themes)